# #Facebook Why I use different accounts log in but log in with the same account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have 2 accounts for example like this:

1. xxxx80524@yahoo.com.tw
2. xxxx80524@gmail.com

I've had these accounts for 10 years at least.

They all still worked at my iPhone11 FB App, I can login and logout, see their content and post content, of course smartphone had remember my accounts already.

1 week ago I use new computer and try to login, but they all direct to first account, even I use incognito window.

I don't know what happend, anyone have the same experience?